# Blank page in FOSUserBundle register

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I just upgraded my Symfony 2.2.2 project to 2.3. I'm also using FOSUserBundle. This bundle works fine in project 2.2.2. but when I upgrade then route /user/register doesn't work anymore. Whole page is blank. Route /login works fine and I can login to my page, but register page is blank. I didn't change anything in this bundle.

In composer.json I have:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",        
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.4.*@dev",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.3.*@dev",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "dev-master",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "dev-master",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master",
    "knplabs/knp-time-bundle": "dev-master",
    "ornicar/gravatar-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "ob/highcharts-bundle": "dev-master",
    "whiteoctober/breadcrumbs-bundle": "dev-master"
},
```

my /app/config/routing.yml

```
#...
user:
    resource: "@AcmeUserBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /user/profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /user/register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /user/resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /user

# Internal routing configuration to handle ESI
#_internal:
#    resource: "@FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/routing/internal.xml"
#    prefix:   /_internal
```

and file: /src/Acme/UserBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

```
user_list:
    pattern:  /admin/user/list
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeUserBundle:Default:list }

user_change_role:
    pattern:  /admin/user/change-role/{id}/{role}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeUserBundle:Default:role }
    requirements:
        id:  \d+
```

Anybody know the solution to the problem?

Comment: is your route enabled? try running `php app/console router:debug`

Comment: yes, route is enabled: fos_user_registration_register ANY ANY ANY  /user/register/

Comment: can you show your user bundle routing config file (ex: AcmeUserBundle\Resources\config\routing.yml)?

Comment: I update my question with two routing files.

Comment: Did u solve it? I have the same issue, the /register route throws blank page

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, for me the error was my routing.
There were two indexActions with the same route. When I changed this it solved the blank page issue.